# node.js request to docker api gives always error 400

Tags: node.js, node-request, docker-api

I get always an error 400 when I try to connect to docker api.
When I try it with curl I get an response.

```
const request = require('request');


request('http://unix:/var/run/docker.sock:/v1.37/info', (error, response, body) => {
        console.log('error:', error);
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
        console.log(body);
});
```

---

```
root@e014aa4c09ad:/docker-api# node test.js
error: null
statusCode: 400
400 Bad Request: malformed Host header
```

Comment: what happens if you remove `http://` from the request and just have `unix:/var/run/docker.sock:/v1.37/info` ?

Comment: I get tihs message "error: Error: `unix://` URL scheme is no longer supported. Please use the format `http://unix:SOCKET:PATH`"

Comment: You can use this library instead 
https://github.com/apocas/dockerode

Comment: The problem is the libary can not create services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://github.com/request/request/issues/2327#issuecomment-298317737, you need to set the `Host` header to null.

```
  headers: {
    'host' : null
  },
```